# Mice build a city with cheese and then eat it

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation, stop-motion-animation

This is an old movie, probably made in the 80s that I saw as a kid and any attempts to find it have failed so far. Here are the details that I can remember (though some of them might not be correct or accurate): A group of mice find a huge stack of cheese. They start eating and after a while, they realize that the cheese storage is more than enough. So they decide to reside in there and build a city, with cheese! It was an stop-motion animation, possibly without any voice actors.

One scene that I clearly remember is when the construction of the city was complete and they all went to their homes. A number of them sat around a table made of cheese and they were just staring at each other and didn't know what to do. A mouse kid took a piece of the table to eat, but the parent prevented her from doing so. Then another kid took a bite and eventually, other mice couldn't resist the temptation, although they had enough cheese storage. This triggered the idea of eating their own furniture and after a while, all the mice joined the movement of eating the city.

It's also possible that this was a short film that makes it hard to find. Anyway I appreciate any help in finding the title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm afraid that without some actual science fiction elements, like evidence of uplift, works simply depicting talking or anthropomorphic animals aren't on topic.  Were there any SF aspects?

Comment: @DavidW does _fantasy_ aspects count? I had the impression that the scope of this site is not limited to science fiction.

Comment: How long was this movie?

Comment: @Spencer probably between 30 to 60 minutes. I can't remember exactly

Comment: @polfosolఠ_ఠ Yes, fantasy aspects count, but again, just having talking animals isn't _fantasy_ unless there is actual magic or other fantasy elements.  This was [discussed in meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy), so I'm not trying to be difficult here, I'm just trying to follow community guidance.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/phhl68/tomtnickelodeon_animation_claymation_or_stop/ - Almost certainly the same film mentioned here (alas unsolved). I'm still not seeing any fantasy elements other than the anthropomorphic mice

Comment: Thanks @Valorum , good find! I would abide by the the community's decision.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [talking animals aren't (in exclusion of any other feature) sufficient to make a question on-topic for SFF:SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy).

Comment: I was searching exactly for this cartoon and found this post. Hoped to see any link to it here but no luck :(